# SQL Server : Error with OPENJSON in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, open-json

The following code works in my local instance of Sql Server but fails in remote instance with error Can you please help me out on this. Getting Error@

> 102: Incorrect syntax near '$.Location'

```
If (len(@JsonBODetails) > 0)
Begin
    Insert Into #Temp_BOLines
    SELECT * FROM  
    OPENJSON ( @JsonBODetails )  
    WITH (   
    Location   varchar(2) '$.Location' ,  
    JCA     varchar(4)     '$.JCA'
    )
End
```

Edit: SQL Server version. It is the same in both the cases.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13-OD) (KB4483666) - 14.0.3049.1 (X64) 
>       Dec 15 2018 11:16:42 
>       Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
>       Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Adding the complete procedure to repro this error

```
declare @JsonBODetails varchar(max) 
SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON ( @JsonBODetails )  
WITH (   
Location   varchar(2) '$.Location' ,  
JCA     varchar(4)     '$.JCA'
)
```

Comment: Your SQL looks fine to me. Are you using a version of SQL Server that supports `OPENJSON`? Can you provide a repro of the error?

Comment: What is the database compatibility level? The statement is correct.